# Using Netbeans 12.2. Using the GUI designer I create a button. Shows the button that I create but when I run the application the button is gone

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, windows-10

I am using Java 14. Funny thing is that it used to work. Replaced the hard drive and upgraded the BIOS to no avail. I tried doing the same thing on my laptop and it doesn't work there either. It looks like it has something to do with Netbeans. My fellow Software Engineer doesn't have the problem.

The first screen image has the "Print This Order" button. The second screen image is what the program displays when run. There is no "Print This Order" button.

[image: Image with button.]

[image: Image without button.]

Comment: *"My program doesn't work, how do I fix it?"* - You've given us no information.  We can't just wave our magic wands and make your program work.  Please see [ask] and include all relevant information.

Comment: Here is the screen with the "Print This Order" button.

Comment: Here is the code that creates the button        btnPrntPO.setText("Print This Order");
        btnPrntPO.setMaximumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 20));
        btnPrntPO.setMinimumSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 20));
        btnPrntPO.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(150, 20));
        btnPrntPO.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btnPrntPOActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        pnlPOScannerInputDef.add(btnPrntPO);

Comment: I tried to put this code n the body of the question. It said that I needed to indent it four spaces. I did that but it still would not accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I was not creating the button correctly. I had to copy and paste a working button and rename it.